# Are transactions In Neo4j default or should I manually handle it.I am using Neo4j from Java using the neo4j driver.How should i manage transactions?

Tags: neo4j

I am using Neo4j from Java.The program logic contains running of multiple and manipulating the obtained data to further execute queries against the database.How do I properly include them in a transaction and rollback in case of errors?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Java Driver, see [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-manual/current/session-api/#java-driver-simple-transaction-fn) for some relevant documentation.

If you are using the Java API, see [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/transaction-management/)